# Load Balancer: Inspecting traffic a specific cloud armor WAF rule is denying

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web-application-firewall, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-armor

Got a simple HTTPS Load Balancer with a backend security policy defined in Cloud Armor assigned to its backend. The security policy is a list of the [Cloud Armor WAF rules](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/waf-rules) at differing sensitivity levels.

However, I'm getting some false positives with the incoming traffic failing the WAF rule checks and I would like to see *how* the requests are failing the rules. The logs give me some header information and the rule that the request is failing, but not how the request is failing the WAF check nor the request's contents.

**Is it possible to see the contents of the HTTPS request and how it's failing the specific WAF rule check?**

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67629776/8016720) might help understand Cloud Armor logging.

Comment: That's exactly where I'm up to. I can see what rules are being triggered, but not how they're triggering the rule. Am interested in seeing the contents of the message and / or how the message is triggering the rule

Comment: Have you tried putting Cloud Armor into [verbose logging](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/request-logging#verbose-logging) mode?  It could tell you a bit more about what part of the request is tripping the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to enable [Verbose Logging](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/request-logging#verbose-logging) so that Cloud Armor can generate logs for the requests that matches a security policy. This works for both allowed or blocked requests.

Verbose Logging helps with better visibility into the behavior of your security policies, allows you to understand how they are applied to incoming traffic, so you can troubleshoot any issues that you may encounter.

You can change the level of detail logged for a policy by using the `--log-level flag`. This flag can have the values `NORMAL` or `VERBOSE`:

`--log-level=[NORMAL | VERBOSE]`

For example:

```
gcloud compute security-policies update ca-policy-1 \
    --log-level=VERBOSE
```

Google recommends that you enable verbose logging when you first create a policy, make changes to a policy, or troubleshoot a policy.

Comment: Tried this out and it's much more informative than the normal logging level. Can see what part of the message body violates the WAF policy