# Cloud armor rules not working as expected, how can I see errors?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

could you help me?
I have a website running on App Engine, and I have configured Load Balancer and Cloud Armor.
LB is working but Cloud Armor apparently isn't.
I created the Rules according to the WAF, I had created some custom rules, but I try to make requests in my URL and it returns 200 in everything, even the rule putting it to block.
In the monitoring part, the load balancer receives the requests, but in cloud armor the graph does nothing.
Does anyone know if it's something related to billing, or any solution?
I am grateful!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiCeu.png)

I would like to see at least a 403 in my url '/' when I pass request with parameters like '1'='1" -H "User-Agent: EvilBot"

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67629776/8016720) for tips on Cloud Armor logs and how to read them for debugging.

Comment: Did you actually bind the Cloud Armor rule to your Backend Service/Bucket? What load balancer type are you using? Global? Regional? Network LB?